# Convert non OSGi jars into OSGi bundles as part of Maven build process

Tags: maven, aem, osgi-bundle

In our CQ project we want use some non-osgi jars. Currently we have a separate process other than the build to convert these jars in to OSGi bundles (primarily uses the eclipse plugin project). But is there a perfect way to handle this as part of the Maven build itself? 
So that the entire process would be transparent to the developers [I have seen some some suggestions for this in some blogs. But this too suggests to create another project for the purpose. Since we are using a multi-module maven structure for the project, is it suggested to add a module just to handle these conversions?].

It would be helpful if you can give me some pointers on this.

Thanks and Regards,

San

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may create a wrapper bundle that includes the non-OSGi JARs as [dependencies with the default scope](https://github.com/Cognifide/PoC-Sling-JMS/blob/master/sling-jms-activemq/pom.xml#L85). Then configure the `maven-bundle-plugin` as follows:

- non-OSGi dependencies should be marked as [embedded](https://github.com/Cognifide/PoC-Sling-JMS/blob/master/sling-jms-activemq/pom.xml#L66),
- their Java packages should be [exported](https://github.com/Cognifide/PoC-Sling-JMS/blob/master/sling-jms-activemq/pom.xml#L65),
- if the non-OSGi JARs themselves have some dependencies, you can include them as well or [mark as ignored](https://github.com/Cognifide/PoC-Sling-JMS/blob/master/sling-jms-activemq/pom.xml#L43).

All links references a sample [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/Cognifide/PoC-Sling-JMS/blob/master/sling-jms-activemq/pom.xml) doing exactly this thing - it wraps the non-OSGi ActiveMQ JAR and its dependencies as an OSGi bundle.

Comment: Hi, I wonder what if the jar also has dpenendencies of jar file? I tried maven-bundle-plugin to transform jar A to a bundle. However, when I check the MANIFEST.MF of the generated bundle, I saw in the Import-Package, there are a lot of jar packages which needs to be imported. I think this is a loop. I need to first transfrom jar A to a bundle, then I need to transform its jar dependencies to bundles, then dependencies of dependencies...... As long as there is a jar package in the Import-Package, I can not use bndrun to test this bundle......

Answer (score 4):

You could automatically wrap non-OSGi jars into OSGi bundles using the **p2-maven-plugin**. It will create a valid P2 repository from your jars. The only drawback is, that you have to call maven twice: first to create the repo and then to use it. The plugin can be found here: https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2):

A good reference pom.xml: https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/com.adobe.acs.bundles.twitter4j/blob/master/bundle/pom.xml

The link above wraps twitter4j jar into an osgi bundle. Checks twice what you export and not export any unnecessary packages.

If you want to embed a taglib or need to embed META-INF folder too, see the link below as an example: https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/scripting/jsp-jstl/pom.xml

Some jars are also OSGi bundles, so before you wrap it, download it from maven central and check the MANIFEST.MF file inside the jar file.